# How to avoid "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given" in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for my project. In model I have written a function  to verify whether similar datas are available or not. I have used rowcount() too. But I can't solve the problem.
Here is my code:

```
public function  student_verification()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $verification = $this->input->post('verification');
    $row = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM student_sign_up WHERE email = '$email' AND verification = '$verification'  ");
    if(mysql_num_rows($row)>0)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Kindly use `$row->num_rows();` instead of `mysql_num_rows($row)` .

Have look here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html .

It will return the number of the rows.